# HTTP Post Header Data can be seen in web browser

Tags: asp.net, post, http-headers

In Firefox using FireBug addon, the data you entered can be seen in POST headers. I wonder if this is a security flaw in the asp.net web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not.  If a browser doesn't expose the headers, other tools will.  They're public by nature except to the degree that https encryption keeps third parties from reading them.